# jQuery hide or remove element based on attribute change

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am working with my website and I am looking for some way in which I can use jQuery to show or add my element `div#content1` when my `#nav-home-tab` is `aria-selected=true` and hide or remove the element if `aria-selected=false`

---

This is my current attempt:

```
/*
This code below is Bootstrap Nav tabs that will show div#content1/2 if clicked(aria-selected=true)
*/
<nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
       <div id="content1">
            //some content
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
      <div id="content2">
            //some content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When it changes or when rendering?

Comment: `$("#content1").toggle($("#nav-home-tab").attr("aria-selected")=="true")`

Comment: @Christopher Jordan Please approve if answer is correct or update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a simple check on Jquery Ready function,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('a#nav-home-tab').attr('aria-selected') == "true") {
        $('div#content1').show();
    } else {
        $('div#content1').hide();
    }  
});
```

You can also see the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vaibhavsah/xnk0yw5h/) here

Answer (score -1):

one little small hack that i will do is
append the element with id "nav-home-tab" with onclick attribute
it would be like this

```
<a onclick="toggleThatDiv()" class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
```

then i will check the attribute "display" on element with id "content1"

```
function toggleThatDiv()
{
    if ( $("#content1").is(':visible') )
        $("#content1").hide();
    else
        $("#content1").show();
}
```

hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: `$("#content1").toggle()` would be a bit simpler but this is not actually answering the question